# How to debug InvalidArgument error on deleteObjects using aws-sdk for nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-cloud-storage, aws-sdk-js

I'm currently using [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) on version ^2.962.0 in a nodeJS application that I'm working ono to connect to a Google Cloud Storage bucket and delete files but I'm getting the "InvalidArgument: Invalid argument" error.

**obs: the project I'm currently working on used to work with AWS S3 but migrated to GCS so we are using the [Migration from AWS to GSC](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#migration-simple) solutions for now. Other methods and libs work fine.**

Here's part of the code where I'm using deleteObjects method:

```
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';  

const s3 = new S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET,
  endpoint: process.env.S3_ENDPOINT,
  logger: console
}

const bucket = process.env.S3_BUCKET_FILES;
const folderPath = 'someFolder/';

try{
  const objectsKeys: Array<any> = [];
  const objectsList = await s3.listObjects( {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Delimiter: '/',
    Prefix: folderPath
  } ).promise();
    
  objectsList.Contents.forEach( ( file ) => {
    const objectKey = file.Key;

    if ( objectKey === folderPath ) {
      return;
    }
    objectsKeys.push( { Key: objectKey } );
  } );
    await s3.deleteObjects( { //<< There seems to be some error of argument
      Bucket: bucket,
      Delete: {
        Objects: objectsKeys
      }
    } ).promise();
}
catch(err){
console.log(err)
}
```

I have tried all sorts of configurations while passing the params to the s3.deleteObjects method but I can't work around the error:

```
//AWS logs and error
[AWS s3 200 0.378s 0 retries] listObjects({ Bucket: 'myBucket-files', Delimiter: '/', Prefix: 'testFolder/' })
[AWS s3 400 0.216s 0 retries] deleteObjects({
  Bucket: 'myBucket-files',
  Delete: {
    Objects: [
      { Key: 'testFolder/e96ab708dab513e6c00ff21afbf02773' },
      [length]: 1
    ]
  }
})

InvalidArgument: Invalid argument.
    at Request.extractError (C:\...) { // all the path until the error at the package folder
  code: 'InvalidArgument',
  region: null,
  time: 2021-12-29T20:34:04.924Z,
  requestId: null,
  extendedRequestId: undefined,
  cfId: undefined,
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 94.12732588991155
}
```

Does someone know any way to extract the exact argument in such cases or to get a log of expected parameters and delivered so that one could compare it? I've managed to turn on the logger config on the S3 client instance as the [documentation suggests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/logging-sdk-calls.html) but it doesn't seem to be more precise on the debugging. Can anyone spot the error?

Comment: Is the first sentence a typo? I don't think the AWS-sdk is capable of interacting with GCS.

Comment: @CollinD No, the project I'm currently working on used to work with AWS S3 but then migrated to GCS so we are using the [Migration from AWS to GSC](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#migration-simple) solutions for now. But other methods work just fine, it's just this kind of error that is really hard to degub.

Comment: That's mighty fancy, today I learned. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Google Cloud Storage does not support some of aws sdk functions, including deleteObjects. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66253012/14689203) discusses a bit more about this issue. Still, I did not find any other "easy" way to debug this InvalidArgument type of error.